# asp.net get current User Id

Tags: asp.net

In code Behind i have this :

```
 protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Guid guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            string name = TextBoxCategoryName.Text;
           // string user = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
            this.connection.Open();
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "insert into ProfitCategories(name, IdUser) values ( '" + name + "', "+guid+" )";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }
```

but this give error: `Incorrect syntax near 'a8'.`
how to get GUID from current user and insert into database

Comment: Parameterize your query to protect against SQL injection and I bet your problem will be solved.

Comment: Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx
Parametrizing your parameters will protect you against SQL injection and make your application (more) secure.

Comment: Are you getting *null* in the guid? What is the value you are getting for Membership.GetUser() is that also null ?

Comment: f546c6d8-5032-42a8-af48-a68024f38066
 this is my guid

Answer (score 3):

Though Mike has presented you the answer, I would like to draw your attention to use *Stored Procedure* instead of sql queries

```
  try
  {
      Guid guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
      string name = TextBoxCategoryName.Text;

       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
            {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertUserDatails", sqlConnection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name ;
            command.Parameters.Add("@IdUser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = guid ;
            sqlConnection.Open();
            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
            }
  }
catch (SqlException ex)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
     return 0;
  }
```

And here goes the Stored procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertUserDatails 
(
    @name varchar(100),
    @IdUser varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into dbo.ProfitCategories(name, IdUser) 
    values (@name, @IdUser)
END
GO
```

Comment: I'll +1 that for showing code example (even tho you didn't show how to write a SPROC ;)

Comment: @Mike On your suggestion :D .. Now still one thing is left *Connection String* in web.Config ;)

Answer (score 1):

**The small problem**: You are missing single quotes around your GUID. It should be:

```
command.CommandText = "insert into ProfitCategories (name, IdUser) values ( '" + name + "', '" + guid + "' )";
```

But don't do this.

**The big problem**: You are at risk for SQL injection if you fix like that. Use parameters for your SQL statement to appropriately fix, or use a stored procedure.

Reading:

[MSDN SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)